# Google App Engine Bulkloader deep key

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I export the parent key(id as string) of a kind??

I have two kinds. Kind A and Kind B. Kind B is a child of Kind A and when I export I want to know the id of Kind A. What should the export transform be for kind B if I want to write A's key which is an id as well as B's id?

```
- kind: A
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('key', key_is_id=True)
- kind: B
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: ????
      import_transform: transform.create_deep_key(('A', 'a', True),
                                                ('B', 'key', True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer

```
export: 
   - external_name: A
     export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string_n(0)
   - external_name: B
     export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string_n(1)
```

Comment: Thank you God for this answer. Looked for it everywhere - Other folks, please notice the _n at the end of the transform